# Function that simulates how many times an event happened

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function that returns the value of how many time an event happened with a specific probability and when n varies.

```
X~Bin(n,p), p=0.1,
n= varies
```

and it would be something like this

```
happened <- function(n){ ...}
```

For example:

Let assume the probability to rain on a single day is 0.1. 
The function should return the value of how many days it rained when n varies (for example n=10, n= 1000000 and so on).

Comment: You question is a unclear. I suspect that `help("qbinom")` can help you.

Comment: I think you mean simulate...(not stimulate)..? :)

Comment: yes thats correct xD

Answer (score 1):

this is exactly what the `rbinom` function does. This function takes the arguments shown below and generates a random number of draws from a binomial distribution.

```
rbinom(n = 50, #number of trials 
       size = 1, # of size, eg 50 trials with either 1 or 0 outputs
       prob = .01) #probability of success
```

This outputs:

```
> rbinom(n = 20, size = 1, prob = .01)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Now, if you wanted to write a function, you could do something like the following, depending on your requirement:

```
successes <- function(n, size = 1, prob = 0.01){
  trials <- rbinom(n = n, size = size, prob = prob)

  sum(trials)
}
```

This function takes the space basic inputs and just sums the successful trials to tell you how many times something "happened: