# How to simulate a probability event function?

Tags: r

I have an event that follows the below code (see [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57955003/function-that-simulates-how-many-times-an-event-happened/57956023#57956023)) that outputs the total number of success from n, binomial trials.

```
successes <- function(n, size = 1, prob = 0.01){
event <- function(n, size = 1, prob = 1/100){
trials <- rbinom(n = n, size = size, prob = prob)

  sum(trials)
}
event(1000)
```

Where event(n) tells how many times the event did happen.

Now I would want to simulate the function (when n=1000) 300000 times and know how many times the event happened. (So not when n=300000 but what values does the above function return when it is repeated 300000 times).

Answer (score 1):

Original function:

```
successes <- function(n, size = 1, prob = 0.01){
  trials <- rbinom(n = n, size = size, prob = prob)

  sum(trials)
}
```

Use the replicate function:

```
results <- replicate(n = 300000 , successes(1000, prob = .1), simplify = TRUE)
```

Which returns a vector with the function run 3e6 times.